# C++20 concepts : specify required constructor for template with specific arguments

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have some class that generates big random sequence and after converts some part of it to a sequence (vector, list, deque etc.) like this:

```
class CRandomSequenceGenerator
{
public:
    template<CoRandomSequenceGeneratorContainer TContainer> // CoRandomSequenceGeneratorContainer is the concept to be specified
    TContainer GetValues(size_t arraySize) noexcept
    {
        using TData = TContainer::value_type;
        TData* ptr; // here will be pointer to the memory range
        TContainer container(ptr, ptr + arraySize);
        return container;
    }
};
```

`TContainer` has to be able to get this memory range, i. e. `TContainer::TContainer(TData*, TData*)` has to be compiled.
I'm specifying concept for this case:

```
template<typename TContainer>
concept CoRandomSequenceGeneratorContainer = requires(typename TContainer::value_type* pdata)
{
    TContainer::TContainer(pdata, pdata);
};
```

Afrer this I'm trying to call it:

```
CRandomSequenceGenerator* gen;
auto vb1 = gen->GetValues<std::vector<uint8_t>>(512);
```

And I get the error in Visual Studio 2022:

```
error C2672: 'C::GetValues': no matching overloaded function found
message : could be 'TContainer C::GetValues(size_t) noexcept'
message : the associated constraints are not satisfied
message : the concept 'CoRandomSequenceGeneratorContainer<std::vector<uint8_t,std::allocator<uint8_t>>>' evaluated to false
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your concept doesn't express what you think it should. `TContainer::TContainer(pdata, pdata);` isn't an expression statement constructing a temporary `TContainer`.

```
template<typename TContainer>
concept CoRandomSequenceGeneratorContainer = requires(typename TContainer::value_type* pdata)
{
    TContainer(pdata, pdata);
};
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a78f3fa1ab3f7ef6)

Comment: But it is not an error, so it does express something. And what is it from the C++ compiler PoV?

Comment: @OleksandrN.: "*But it is not an error*" That's not how templates work (and concepts are templates). You don't get most errors in templates until you try to instantiate them. And in a concept, most instantiation "errors" lead to the concept evaluating to `false`; which is what happened here.